# Convert IIS Web Application to folder and back

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to write a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script that capture the names of all of my IIS Applications and converts them back to folders. Then takes that same set of names and converts them back to Applications. I have a problem with my loop and I believe it has to do with the format of the input variable `$AppNames`

I attempted an `$AppNames.ToString()` but that didn't work. Any Ideas?

```
$AppNames1 = Get-Webapplication -Site "Mgmtservice" | Select @{e={$_.Path.Trim('/')};l="Name"} | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
$AppNames1

$Site = "MgmtService"

ForEach ($AppName in $AppNames)
{
  Remove-WebApplication -Name $_ -Site MgmtService
}

Start-Sleep 6

ForEach ($AppName in $AppNames)
{
  $Path1 = "IIS:\Sites\Mgmtservice\"
  $Path = $Path1 + $AppName
  ConvertTo-WebApplication -PSPath $Path
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that format-table messes with the output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors in your code, e. g. you are using `$_` in your foreach loop where you should had use `$AppName`. Or you iterate over `$AppNames` but you assigned the output from `Get-Webapplication` to `$AppNames1`. Also you shouldn't use `Format-Table` there.

So I tried to fix all that stuff, just give it a try:

```
$AppNames = Get-Webapplication -Site "Mgmtservice" | ForEach-Object { $_.Path.Trim('/')}
$AppNames | ForEach-Object { Remove-WebApplication -Name $_ -Site MgmtService }
Start-Sleep 6
$AppNames | ForEach-Object { ConvertTo-WebApplication -PSPath (Join-Path 'IIS:\Sites\Mgmtservice\' $_) }
```

Comment: whats the difference `$_` or `$appname`. they are the same?

Comment: @4c74356b41 No, `$_` is the *pipeline object* whereas `$appname` is a variable assigned to the current element in an iteration. They have nothing in common and `$_` doesn't work in his example.

Comment: Martin thank you the lesson. I am somewhat self taught so I appreciate you making that clarification for me about $_ and $AppName. I will check out the code and let you know.